# Using sleep in Ruby Watir tests

Tags: ruby, watir, acceptance-testing

My Watir acceptance tests tend to fail in cases where I don't use Ruby's `sleep` function. Here is an example:

```
it 'Edit case: should edit display name of TEST' do
    all_row = @browser.trs(:css => ".ui-sortable-data-row")
    # note: this displays a detail view of the selected item of a table
    all_row[0].td.fire_event :click

    # click on edit button (activate edit mode)
    #sleep 1
    @browser.span(:css => "p-header a > span.fa-pen").fire_event :click

    # set name value
    @browser.text_field(:id => "name").set("test name")

    # ...
end
```

If the `sleep 1` (sleep for 1 second) function call is missing, the test will fail with the following message:

```
Failure/Error: @browser.text_field(:id => "name").set("test name")

 Watir::Exception::ObjectDisabledException:
   element present, but timed out after 10 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::TextField: located: true; {:id=>"name", :tag_name=>"input"}> to be enabled
```

However, if I explicitly call `sleep 1`, the text field ('name') is enabled and can be set.

So my question is: Is using the `sleep` function a good practice or is there a better way to avoid these problems?

Comment: In test is a common practice ... look at [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268930/is-there-a-way-to-slow-down-execution-of-watir-webdriver-under-cucumber)

Comment: Using `sleep` (ie explicit waits) is not considered good practice. You could be sleeping more than you have to (ie wasting execution time) or not waiting enough (ie still flaky tests). Implicit waits, ie waiting for a specific condition, are a better choice. My first suggestion would be to use `#click` instead of `#fire_event`. `#click` has some waiting logic to make sure the element is clickable. If that doesn't work, we might need more details about the application to determine why the click isn't working.

Comment: What version of Watir are you using? There was a bug that we recently fixed that might be affecting this.

Comment: @JustinKo a quick quibble on definitions. In the Selenium world, an "Implicit Wait" is when the responsibility of waiting for an element to be located is assigned to the driver via timeout value setting, and an "Explicit Wait" is when you poll for the expected condition in the code, (and "Static Sleeps" are when you are being lazy and just hard code it).

Comment: @titusfortner, thanks for the correction. In Watir, would you consider the automatic waiting, eg waiting for an element to exist, to be an "implicit wait"?

Comment: @Justin Ko Implicit wait of selenium happens via DRIVER, Watir waiting is equivalent  to selenium Explicit wait because selenium Explicit wait is happening via local language binging, WATIR follows the same. WATIR handles the waiting via local language binging. That's why we can verify the status of the element in WATIR, Biggest advantage!

Comment: @JustinKo I like the idea of the implicit wait as a global waiting strategy, but not the webdriver implementation. Watir has taken the concept two steps further by waiting for the element to be ready for the specific action being called on it, not just for it to exist in the DOM, and we've implemented that without making unnecessary additional wire calls. I went through a bunch of names for it in Watir: smart waits, automatic waits, and I ended up calling the toggle "relaxed wait." When I give training on Test Frameworks I describe this type of wait as an "Abstract Wait."

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I'm using watir (6.14.0) and watir-rspec (3.0.0). Using `#click` seemed to have helped.